# Samsung Tablet. Show apps in landscape. Default value for app

Tags: android, android-manifest, orientation, landscape, galaxy-tab

Samsung Tablets has screen settings for everyone app on device (**Settings/Advanced features/Labs/Show apps in landscape**). This setting may have different for some apps by default, usually **App Default** or **App aspect ratio** (img1).
With **App aspect ratio** apps stay in Portrait mode when device is in Landscape mode (img2). I can't find any description of dependecies of this setting value.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG7bf.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Atb.jpg)

Maybe someone know, what I need to change in AndroidManifest.xml, build.gradle or maybe Activity implementation to receive **App Default** as a default value?

Answer (score 0):

Most apps which have locked the orientation, I believe, are doing it via the AndroidManifest.xml in the launcher activity by using the attribute `android:screenOrientation`, under the respective `<activity>` tag

Ref: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#:~:text=task%20aren%27t%20resizable.-,android%3AscreenOrientation,-The%20orientation%20of](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#:%7E:text=task%20aren%27t%20resizable.-,android%3AscreenOrientation,-The%20orientation%20of)

The list which you're mentioning can be populated using `ActivityInfo` class' field `screenOrientation`.